# vehicular pollution

Tags: pollution, environmental-protection, air-pollution

Is there any way to convert the vehicular emissions from cars during journey to oxygen or safer gases to eliminate/decrease vehicular pollution?

My question is keeping in mind most populated and polluted countries where majority of people can't afford for/not willing to buy H<sub>2</sub>-run cars nor get rid of existing fuel cars nor interested in using bicycles.

In simple terms: Is there a possibility for real time  emission converter? Do they already exist or is there any research in this area? Any kind of help is appreciated.

Thank you

EDIT: re-posted at [Sustainablity](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/6318/is-there-any-way-to-recycle-air-pollution-into-fertilizer) & [Engineering](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/18461/is-there-any-method-to-recycle-air-pollution-into-fertilizer)

Comment: Do you mean reducing emissions of particulate matter, VOCs, and NOx? There are technologies, such aß catalysts, that reduce emissions of some air pollutants. Also the driving behaviour can lead to a reduction of emissions of some pollutants. However, reducing emissions of one pollutant might increase emissions of another pollutant. Just to Make sure: you are asking for reducing air pollutants and not for climate-change-relevant emissions, such as CO2 and Methane?

Comment: Please clarify: Do you need this information to calculate transport-sector emissions supplied into a chemistry transport model? (edit: Please clarify as soon as possible)

Comment: No @Daniel.Neumann. Just random question whose solutions I am unaware of.

Comment: CTM is good idea though for real time emission convertor.

Comment: Unfortunately, the question is off-topic here. Please consider asking at [Mechanis.SE](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/) or at [Sustainability.SE](http://sustainability.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: But, CTM is just first step to now which chemicals to be converted. we need some embedded system attached to vehicles that makes the chemicals converted and released to environment and make air less polluted to breath.

Comment: This SE community is not about technical solutions for emission reductions.  The people at the Mechanics and Sustainability communities know more about such solutions. If your were doing chemistry transport, meteorological, or climate modeling **and** you were trying to improve the input emissions **and** you were looking for rough estimations of maximum technical feasible reductions, then - in my opinion - one could argue that the question was in the scope of this community. I think the question is quite interesting. But unfortunately, it is out of scope.